# change all values in a date column to the end of the month

Tags: sql, sas

I have a column 'timestamp' in format Datetime. To merge with another table it would be very convenient to create a column that transforms:

```
 06AUG2015:21:42:44
```

Into

```
 31AUG2015:00:00:00
```

Any ideas how to go about this?

Comment: Please read the documentation on the INTNX() function.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to create a DATE value instead of another DATETIME value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run [`intnx`](https://go.documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=p10v3sa3i4kfxfn1sovhi5xzxh8n.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en#p05mtdxbgua535n1rfbkiwqb4asq) function. Example:

```
data dates;
format d1 d2  DATETIME20. d3 date9. d4 DATETIME20.;
d1 = '06AUG2015:21:42:44'dt;
/*E as last parameter mean END*/
d2 = intnx('dtMonth', d1, 0,"E");
d3=datepart(d2);
d4 = dhms(d3,0,0,0);
run;
```

> d1 -- initial date
>
> d2 -- the last date of month
>
> d3 -- date part of last date of month
>
> d4 -- date with dropped HMS to zeros

Result

```
+--------------------+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+
|         d1         |         d2         |    d3     |         d4         |
+--------------------+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+
| 06AUG2015:21:42:44 | 31AUG2015:23:59:59 | 31AUG2015 | 31AUG2015:00:00:00 |
+--------------------+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+
```

**P.S.**
thank you @Tom

```
data dates;
format d1 d4 DATETIME20.;
d1 = '06AUG2015:21:42:44'dt;
d4 = intnx('dtday',intnx('dtMonth', d1, 0,'E'),0,'B');
run;
```

Comment: Just to point out that these functions are available in `proc SQL` as well, unless you are using pass-thru SQL.  In that case, you need to use the capabilities of the underlying database.

Comment: That is a very useful function! 

Thank you

Comment: `intnx('dtday',intnx('dtMonth', d1, 0,'E'),0,'B')`

Answer (score 0):

You can join on the `intnx` without having to create a new column.

Example, presuming `transaction` table has column `timestamp` that contains SAS datetime values, and `monthEnd` table has column `dayStamp` that contains SAS date time values restricted to the start of the last day of a month.

```
select 
  … 
from 
  transaction as WithinMonth
join 
  monthEnd
on
  intnx('dtMonth', WithinMonth.timestamp, 1, 'B') - 86400
  /* computed: start of last day of month that contains timestamp */
  = 
  monthEnd.dayStamp
```